# Java FastCGI Socket (How do I communicate with a FastCGI server?)

Tags: java, php, sockets, fastcgi

I'm trying find out how to communicate with a PHP FastCGI server using Java Sockets. However google is of no help at all.

I've read that the FastCGI protocol is a binary one, but that's all I know of it.

I need to send the following:

- A HTTP request
- The document root (i.e. the root directory, which may change depending on host)
- The file to parse (which may be located in a virtual directory, Although I'm not sure about this one, it might be better to send the virtual root as doc root)

How do I send a HTTP request I received in my Java application to PHP FastCGI using sockets (java.net.Socket)? (assuming the server is already running)

Comment: Another question. How can you know this is a viable option when you don't understand the protocol? Could you explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955595/java-connection-to-php